# How two rsync two directory pairs (src1->dest1 and src2->dest2) with a single command?

Tags: command-line, rsync

I am using rsync to run a backup from one drive to another. There are two pairs of source and destination directories, and I can't figure out how to make it work with a single command. I'm currently running two separate commands to do the full backup.

The source directories are separate mountpoints: `/mnt/ssd_ext4` and `/mnt/ssd_ntfs`. There are matching mountpoints on the destination drive: `/mnt/backup_ext4` and `/mnt/backup_ntfs`.

The full commands are

`rsync -aAXUxv --no-l --no-D --delete --info=progress2,stats2 --debug=FILTER --exclude-from=/home/xxx/excludelist.txt /mnt/ssd_ext4/ /mnt/backup_ext4`

and

`rsync -aAXUxv --no-l --no-D --delete --info=progress2,stats2 --debug=FILTER --exclude-from=/home/xxx/excludelist.txt /mnt/ssd_ntfs/ /mnt/backup_ntfs`

Is there some clever way to do these from a single command?

---

**Edit:**

Thank you for suggesting alternatives, but I really need the single command. Once I figure it out, I'm going to use rsync over ssh with the "forced command" option tied to an ssh key. I only get to map a single command with that method. I didn't mention this because I was trying to keep the question simple...

Comment: You can run one after the other. What do you expect to happen with a hypothetical combined approach?

Comment: You can have multiple **source** folders in `rsync`, but there can be only one **destination** folder

Comment: Create a bash script with those commands and run bash script. My first bash script was just several commands copied from my bash history. https://askubuntu.com/questions/471285/how-to-create-execute-a-script-file/471286#471286 &  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents

Comment: Thanks Hermann, Seamus, and oldfred! I added an edit, explaining why I actually need a single command.

Comment: Why do you need to use SSH to copy files within a single host?

Comment: @JimL. At that point it'll be to a remote server. I could create two keys, and use each one as a vector for one of the two commands, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Rsync is very good at tasks like `rsync  src1 src2 ... srcN  dest_dir/`

Within a single invocation, you can fundamentally only backup
to a single destination directory.
For two destinations, you will need to run the rsync protocol
two separate times.
You could invent your own protocol to efficiently accomplish that,
but it wouldn't be the battle-tested rsync protocol.

> There are two pairs of source and destination directories,

> I'm going to use rsync over ssh with the "forced command" option

The "two destinations" requirement is incompatible with
using stock rsync.
Consider going up a level so there is just a single destination.

For example, using a much simpler `tar` pipeline where
we unconditionally send all the bits on every invocation,
we might use:

```
cd /mnt && tar zcf - ssd_ext4/ ssd_ntfs/ |
  ssh server 'cd /mnt && tar zxvf -'
```

Since we're renaming

- `ssd_ext4` --> `backup_ext4`, and
- `ssd_ntfs` --> `backup_ntfs`

we will initially need to "fix it with symlinks" on the server.

```
cd /mnt
mkdir -p backup_{ext4,ntfs}
ln -s backup_ext4 ssd_ext4
ln -s backup_ntfs ssd_ntfs
```

I imagine one could persuade rsync to follow a similar arrangement.
I have never had occasion to jump through such hoops,
and symlink handling tends to be treated specially.
Carefully test it in a QA environment before messing with production.

---

## double copy

On the server, `mkdir double_dest`.

Now you can `rsync` two source directories to that `double_dest/`,
taking advantage of rsync's efficient use of network bandwidth
when some of the bits are already at the destination.

After the rsync completes, the server is free to perform
additional local disk-to-disk rsync's from double_dest/
to the final resting place for those bits.
Performing local copies reduces the exposure of an errant
network client potentially writing to more locations than intended, and even lets you take advantage of `chroot()` if you wish.
But it comes at a "double storage" cost -- you would have
to purchase twice as much storage, perhaps in the form
of cheap rotating Winchester disks.

---

## requirements engineering

> I really need the single command. Once I figure it out, I'm going to use rsync over ssh with the "forced command" option

No, you do not need a single command.
You could choose to impose "single command" as part
of your requirements document, but that would tend
to increase the cost of implementing a solution.

You have an off-the-shelf solution already available,
staring you in the face.
Should we tell sshd about a single forced command?
No.
Just define a pair of such commands,
each with a distinct destination directory.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Several have mentioned `rsync`'s multi-source, single-destination ability, and @J_H suggests going up a level and using symlinks, but in the interest of joining all the dots:

On the backup server, assuming your disk partitions are GPT-labeled
as 'ssd_ext4' and 'ssd_ntfs':

```
for fs in ext4 ntfs
do
  mkdir -p /backup/ssd_$fs
  ln -s ssd_$fs /backup/backup_$fs
  mount /dev/disk/by-partlabel/ssd_$fs /backup/ssd_$fs
done
```

<sup>[For some OSes, the device would be more like `/dev/gpt/ssd_$fs`.]</sup>

Then you can push backups from the client onto the backup server:

```
rsync ...options.... /mnt/ssd_ext4 /mnt/ssd_ntfs backup_server:/backup/
```